# make all error message for Caffe installation: libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4 and libopencv_core.so.2.4

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, caffe

Following instructions for installing Caffe on Ubuntu 16.04 (GPU), after performing `make all` I receive:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_core.so.2.4, needed by .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so, may conflict with libopencv_core.so.4.0
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4, needed by .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so, may conflict with libopencv_imgproc.so.4.0
```

How do I circumvent this error and proceed to make as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have several conflicting installations of OpenCV (2.4 and 4.0). Uninstall the undesired one and recompile Caffe.